# gedit from the command line: new window or tab?

Tags: gnome, xfce, window-management, gedit, gsettings

I'm trying to customize the behavior of gedit when I launch a new instance from the command line. In the past, the default was "open a new tab if there's a existing window in the current workspace, otherwise open a new window". At some point, this shifted to "open a new tab if there's a gedit window open anywhere, otherwise open a new tab in an existing window, with the host window seemingly chosen at random". The new behavior is kind of annoying, and I'd like to recover the old behavior.

After some searching, the closest I could find was this thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/219046/configure-gedit-to-always-open-in-new-window, where the author wants to always open a new window when a text file is double clicked. That's not what I'm looking for, but it does suggest editing gedit's behavior with gsettings. After looking through my gsettings options, the only one that seems to be related is show-tabs-mode. Currently, it's set to "auto". When I set it to "never"

`gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui show-tabs-mode never`

I get the behavior that when I open a file with gedit from the command line, the new window replaces a tab in an existing window, even if that window is in another workspace. That's really not what I want.

I'd be grateful for any ideas!

For context, I'm running xfce on a gentoo system. It's possible that xfce just doesn't play well with gnome applications, but I'm optimistic since this behavior did exist in the past.